# How to set/disable the OutlinedTextField focus?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

**What I want:**

1. I want my OutlinedTextField to be always focused or disable the ability to focus.
2. I want the OutlinedTextField to be RoundedCornerShape but when I use background it goes out of the shape.

**My Code:**

```
Column(modifier = Modifier
    .weight(1f)
    .background(Color.Gray)
    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(35.dp))

) {
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = "12",
        onValueChange = {},
        readOnly = true,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(35.dp),
        textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(textAlign = TextAlign.End),
        leadingIcon = { Icon(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_coin), contentDescription = null)},
        modifier = Modifier
    )
}
```

Comment: what does it mean "always focused" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `enabled = false` the text field will be neither editable nor focusable, the input of the text field will not be selectable, visually text field will appear in the disabled UI state readOnly.

To change the background color use the attribute `backgroundColor` in the `TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors` parameter:

```
    OutlinedTextField(
        value = "12",
        onValueChange = {},
        enabled = false,
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(35.dp),
        textStyle = LocalTextStyle.current.copy(textAlign = TextAlign.End),
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.outlinedTextFieldColors(
            backgroundColor = Color.Gray,
            disabledTextColor= LocalContentColor.current.copy(LocalContentAlpha.current),
        )
    )
```

[image]

If you want to wrap the component in a Column change the order of the modifiers:

```
Column(modifier = Modifier
    .clip(RoundedCornerShape(35.dp))
    .background(Color.Gray)
){
  //....
}
```

If you want to change the border width you have to use the version 1.2.x and the `OutlinedTextFieldDecorationBox` specifying the `border` attribute:

```
   BasicTextField(
      //....
    ) {
        OutlinedTextFieldDecorationBox(
            border = {
                TextFieldDefaults.BorderBox(
                    //...
                    unfocusedBorderThickness = 4.dp,
                    focusedBorderThickness = 4.dp
                )
            }
        )
    }
```

Comment: thank you, this is what I wanted. how can I change the border width?

Comment: @AloneWalker you can't do it with the `OutlinedTextField` .You have to use the version **1.2** and `BasicTextField` + `OutlinedTextFieldDecorationBox`